# Ubuntu 22.04 katlooon installation errors when running git commands and directory doesnt exist

Tags: apt, 22.04, git, chmod, kali

im on ubuntu 22.04(?) and im trying to install kali repo apps (im still learning Linux i might sound confusing) and i installed git in terminal but when trying to get katloon it installs the first time and now it says theres a directory but i cant cd into it or find it in files and my chmod command or sudo ./katloon that command wont work either

Comment: Anything Kali-related is not recommended for learners: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/524752